# Mongoose - Best practice to work with typescript objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I want to work in a sperate logic to Object in the code and DB object.
The all idea is to isolate completly to real logic from DB stuff (for couple reason...one of them is if I would want to work with other DB in the future)

For now I am working with MongoDB, and I created some infractractures that can handle creation and write typescript object to DB and it is something like this:

```
import Address, { AddressSchema } from './addressDetails';
import { Document, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

export default class User {
  name: String;
  address: Address;

  constructor(params: { name: String, address: Address }) {
    this.name = params.name;
    this.address = params.address;
  }
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  details: AddressSchema
});

export interface UserDocument extends User, Document { };

export const UserModel = model<UserDocument>('User', UserSchema);
```

now Address is a other object that look like this:

```
import { Document, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

export default class Address {
    country: String;
    city: String;
    streetAddress: String;

    constructor(params: { country: String, city: String, streetAddress: String }) {
        this.country = params.country;
        this.city = params.city;
        this.streetAddress = params.streetAddress;
    }
}

export const AddressSchema = new Schema({
    country: String,
    city: String,
    streetAddress: String
});
```

So actually Address is a nested schema inside User.
So when I save UserModel it is look like this:

```
const newUser = new User(newUserParams);
const newUserModel = new UserModel(newUser);

public saveModel(newUserModel): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        newUserModel.save((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                log('error', err, undefined, undefined);
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Inside the DB the User that we saved is looks like nested inforamation with ID for the Address section.

Now the things that I don't know is how do I read a document and parse is so I can create an new **full** instance of User main object.

By **full** I mean that it will create also instance of the nested Address inforamtion that comes from the document.

Thank you guys very much!

Comment: Show us the code you use to save your model.

Comment: @JeroenHeier - Added it! :)